# Why is the index out of range when the size is defined by a variable?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, properties

When I define the size of an integer array using a variable I get the error: "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled". However, if I just put the same value as the variable that I used, it works.

I'll explain it in comments better below:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim test As Test

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        test = New Test(5) 'the length property is test is 5
        test.AddToList()
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Test

    Dim _length As Integer
    Public Property length() As Integer
        Get
            Return _length
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _length = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Dim _magnitude(length, 2) As Integer 'Size is length, which should be equal to 5. If I remove length and just put 5, it works fine.
    Public Property magnitude As Integer(,)
        Get
            Return _magnitude
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer(,))
            _magnitude = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal lengthp As Integer)
        length = lengthp 'Sets 5 to the length property.
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddToList()
        magnitude(4, 0) = 4 'Operates on the magnitude property. This is where the error is located.
        Debug.Print(magnitude(4, 0))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Hopefully you guys understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private fields are initialized prior to the constructor. When you instantiate the class, `_magnitude` is initialized before `length` is set, so what you get is the equivalent of `Dim _magnitude(0, 2) As Integer`.

Try changing your declaration to something like:

```
Dim _magnitude(,) As Integer
'...
Public Sub New(ByVal lengthp As Integer)
    length = lengthp
    ReDim _magnitude(lengthp, 2) As Integer
End Sub
```

You also talk about length, so you should keep in mind that you're specifying the upper bound of the array, not the length.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dim` statement for the `_magnitude` member variable occurs before the constructor. Change your code as follows:

```
  Dim _magnitude(,) As Integer '<<Changed. Don't set the bounds here, just declare the variable
  Public Property magnitude As Integer(,)
    Get
      Return _magnitude
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer(,))
      _magnitude = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Sub New(ByVal lengthp As Integer)
    length = lengthp 'Sets 5 to the length property.
    ReDim _magnitude(length, 2) '<<Added. Set the bounds AFTER the length property has been set
  End Sub
```